# Export CoreAnimation to video file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I wrote a basic animation framework using Core Animation on iPhone. It has the functionality for pause and resume of animations and also can run animations at specified time. My basic problem is that I cannot find a way to export my animations to a video file (.mov, .avi etc). I have read about `AVAssetWriter` and `AVComposition` but cannot understand how to make them work in my case.

By searching the internet the closest I was able to get was it by doing frame by frame reading of my animations. Even for it I could not find a way to make it work and could not find that whether iPhone SDK have something to do that for this kind of frame by frame reading in my case. I also came close to this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031721/coreanimation-avfoundation-and-ability-to-make-video-export) and still could not figure out (sorry if I feel that I am beginner in those things, but I am not, just could not understand some things)

If anyone know how to make it work or even how to something similar to it please share. And if there is no way then if you know any other way to do i.e using OpenGL ES instead of CoreAnimation please share it too.

Comment: Take a look <a href="file:///Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableVideoComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009643">AVMutableVideoComposition.animationTool</a>. I'm pretty sure you need to create a AVMutableComposition and export it by the AVAssetExportSession

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have tried both but could not make them work. Now am currently working on a workaround that reads my animations frame by frame in images. It is working and reading frame by frame which is accomplished by getting frame by scheduling a timer to my method. It works for 30 fps reading but I want to convert my animations with much more fps which gets slowed because of NSTimer. Now I want to know is there any better way for this kind of thing ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but did you manage to get an `UIImage *` from your animation without rendering it on screen? How? (renderInContext ignore transforms, so it killed one idea I had some time ago =(  ). I have some code to do a video file from an array of images, do you want it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Marcelo. That is the main problem I was facing i.e to get UIImage* from the animation without rendering it on screen. I can get UIImage* by renderInContext on presentation layer. I got the images of the animations frame by frame but it depends on NSTimer because the timer calls my getCurrentFrame method at interval of 1/30 second. I want to speed up the process by setting say 1/600 second so the video (20 min animation is recorded in 1 min) is made fast but timer skips some frames due to too much low speed. I want an alternate way of calling my method at such low speed.

Comment: @MarceloAlves Any chance you still have that code/are willing to share? Just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @Azeem Do you found any solution for your problem? I have the same situation and i would like to found an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Check this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/advanced-media-manipulation-with-av-foundation
Around page 84 he talks about adding animation to video compositions. I believe this will help you get what you need.

> > EDIT: Specifically you need to look at the animationTool of your video composition. This is a AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool object that allows you to add a core animation layer to your output video. See also this question:
> >     [Recording custom overlay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443564/recording-custom-overlay-on-iphone)
> >     I am sorry I do not have the time to get you a full code snippet, but basically you set this animation tool of your video composition, and then create an AVAssetExportSession and set its videoComposition to the one you made.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is a very valuable resource but it doesn't resolve my problem.